# How to clone/copy .docx file with keeping all styles and alignments using python docx

Tags: python, docx, python-docx

I want to clone docx file with all of its styles and alignments. This is my code :

```
import docx
from docx import Document

doc = docx.Document('my_word_file.docx')
allText = []
for docpara in doc.paragraphs:
    allText.append((docpara.text).replace('a' ,'s')

mydoc = docx.Document()
mydoc.add_paragraph(allText)
mydoc.save("cloned.docx")
```

So I am fixing some mistakes and file is saving , but without styles or tabs or enters.
How to keep changes and stylings too ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the way is to write your own function to copy the text and style of each paragraph. Here is a first implementation of what you could do:

```
from docx import Document

def copy_paragraph(output_doc, paragraph):

    output_paragraph = output_doc.add_paragraph()
    # Alignment data of whole paragraph
    output_paragraph.paragraph_format.alignment = paragraph.paragraph_format.alignment
    for row in paragraph.runs:
        output_row = output_paragraph.add_run(row.text)
        # Font data
        output_row.style.name = row.style.name
        # Size of font data
        output_row.font.size = row.font.size
        # Bold data
        output_row.bold = row.bold
        # Italic data
        output_row.italic = row.italic
        # Underline data
        output_row.underline = row.underline
        # Color data
        output_row.font.color.rgb = row.font.color.rgb
    
doc = Document('my_word_file.docx')
mydoc = Document()
for paragraph in doc.paragraphs:
    copy_paragraph(mydoc, paragraph)
mydoc.save("cloned.docx")
```

I don't exclude that there may be other parameters that need to be copied (for example the highlighting of the text, etc.). In this case I suggest you to do some tests and consult the [docx documentation](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) that is pretty well written.